# Проверьте, что созданный треугольник не является вырожденным. Если это так, используйте throw new IllegalArgumentException()

Tags: java

Все тесты проходят кроме кроме одного со следующими значениями (new Point(1, 3), new Point(3, 9), new Point(2, 6)

```
if (a.getX() + a.getY() + (b.getX() + b.getY()) <= (c.getX() + c.getY()))
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
```

вот весь код:(сама задача про нахождения площади и цент)

```
class Triangle {
Point a,b,c;
public Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
    //TODO
   length(a, b);
   length2(a, c);
   length3(a, c);

    if (a.getX() + a.getY() + (b.getX() + b.getY()) <= (c.getX() + c.getY()))
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}

public static double length(Point a, Point b)
{
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b.getX()- a.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(b.getY()- a.getY(), 2.0));
}

 public static double length2(Point a, Point c)
 {
     return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c.getX() - a.getX(), 2)+ Math.pow(c.getY() - a.getY(), 2.0));
 }
 public static double length3(Point b, Point c)
 {
     return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c.getX() - b.getX(), 2)+ Math.pow(c.getY() - b.getY(), 2.0));
 }


public double area() {
    //TODO
    return Math.abs((a.getX() - c.getX()) * (b.getY() - a.getY()) - (a.getX() - b.getX()) * (c.getY() - a.getY())) /2.0;
}


public Point centroid(){
    //TODO
    double x= (a.getX()+b.getX()+c.getX())/3;
    double y= (a.getY()+b.getY()+c.getY())/3;
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

}

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Зачем писать три метода, которые делают одно и то же -- вычисляют длину отрезка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, при создании треугольника проверить точки, вычислить длины сторон и проверить соотношение сторон:

```java
class Triangle {
    private final Point a, b, c;
    private final double ab, ac, bc;

    public Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
        if (null == a || null == b || null == c) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Null point");
        }

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.ab = length(a, b);
        this.ac = length(a, c);
        this.bc = length(b, c);

        if (ab + ac <= bc || ab + bc <= ac || ac + bc <= ab) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid/degenerate triangle");
        }
    }

    public static double length(Point a, Point b) {
        double dx = a.getX() - b.getX();
        double dy = a.getY() - b.getY();
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    public double area() {
        return Math.abs(
            (a.getX() - c.getX()) * (b.getY() - a.getY()) - 
            (a.getX() - b.getX()) * (c.getY() - a.getY())
        ) / 2.0;
    }

    public Point centroid() {
        double x = (a.getX() + b.getX() + c.getX()) / 3;
        double y = (a.getY() + b.getY() + c.getY()) / 3;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```